# MariaDB on Tiny Core linux: terminals database is inaccessible

Tags: linux, shell, mariadb

I installed MariaDB on Tiny Core linux using [this guide](https://willhaley.com/blog/mariadb-in-tinycore-linux-6/).

If I try to open `mysql -u root` I get this error:

> terminals database is inaccessible

I have no idea how can I fix this

**UPD:** I use it on qemu vm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I use openssh to access the vm from ssh. So I've just written this commands and it works now.

```
sudo printf "\nTERM="linux"\nexport TERM" >> "/home/tc/.profile"
sudo echo '/home/tc/.profile' >> /opt/.filetool.lst
filetool.sh -b
```